# Access different values from vector

Tags: java, vector, iteration

I have values in Vector. I have accessed the first value of vector, and that value also contains some more vector. Now, my question is, how to go back and retrieve the second value of main vector. For Example, I have vector `vecLinkHashMapXMLData : [apple - Apple, orange - Orange]`. into the key "apple", it contains more vector. I have retrieve the values of apple, but how can i go back to get the value "orange" ?

Comment: Use `List` instead of `Vector`, `Vector`s are out dated.

Comment: Thanks Ruchira... Its our company coding standards, so cant change it.

Comment: @JB Nizet, I cant paste code because of limited access and security issue. So, please suggest / guide me.

Comment: Then ask someone from your company to help you with this super-secret, sub-standard code.

Comment: Hey JB Nizet, dont try to be oversmart... If you dont want to answer, then please dont waste your time here... better to do some good stuffs...

Comment: @user3307549 Or create a minimal example and post it.

Comment: @Jason.. Sure, i will create an example and will post here soon. Thanks

Comment: It's so goofy when questions like this end up with accepted answers. It's like two people just invented some kind of new secret language that nobody else understands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I am understanding, you have a vector of vectors. According to the [API for the Vector class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html), you can use the `iterator` to go through your elements. So in short:

```
Vector<Vector<...>> outerVec = ...
...

Iterator<Vector<...>> outerIterator = outerVec.iterator();
while(outerIterator.hasNext())
{
     Vector<...> innerVec = outerIterator.next();
     // Work with apple, orange, etc
     Iterator<...> innerIterator = innerVec.iterator();
     while(innerIterator.hasNext())
     {
          //work with Apple, Orange, etc.
     }
}
```